# File marked as locked, always by the same user

Tags: microsoft-office, network-shares, windows-server-2003

The situation is as follows: My user has modify permissions on a network share, as do her colleagues. Whenever someone opens the file, it is locked, and if someone else tries to open it, they are notified that it has been opened. So far, so good.

The problem is that, regardless of what user has actually opened the file, the file is always marked as locked by the same user. The user reports that this only happens with one file.

Applications used: Microsoft Office 2010
Server runs: Windows Server 2003

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I could check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it turns out that this is a known issue, and should be resolved by applying a hotfix.

There is a public blog on file locking issues (http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2012/05/14/the-definitive-locked-file-post.aspx). I would suggest the following:

If you are seeing problems where the file is locked when double clicking from Windows Explorer, but the files open up correctly when opened in Excel or Word, do the following:

Turn off the Preview Pane, Details Pane and pop ups that show information about file and desktop items

This is a problem that has been reported to affect Windows 7 clients only, not Windows XP. The problem here may have something to do with the Windows Explorer in Windows 7. We are currently investigating this further and will post more information as it is available.

In a Windows Explorer window, do the following:
1. Right click on the Start Button. 
2. Click 'Open Windows Explorer'. 
3. At the top left click Organize > Layout 
4. Uncheck Details Pane and Preview Pane.
5. On a Windows menu, click on Tools > Folder Options. In the box that opens up, click on the View tab. Scroll down the list to “Show pop-up description for folder and desktop items” and clear the checkbox and then click OK.

If you are seeing issues where the wrong user name is showing up, there is a known bug on that and a fix:
In cases where the wrong user name is displayed in the file lock dialog

Sometimes where it says 'another user' it has the name of someone that didn't open the file or it has no name at all. Just a big ' ' where a name ought to be. Fear not, there is a fix for this problem. The flavor depends on whether you have Excel 2010 or Excel 2007. The below KB Articles contain hotfixes that address several issues, not just the file locked issue. But in the dialog of the article you will see this as one of the problem descriptions:

Assume that you have an .xls file that is protected by Information Rights Management (IRM) on a network share. When you open the file in Excel 2007, a File In Use dialog box appears. However, the dialog box does not display the correct name of the user who locked the file. Therefore, you cannot edit the file.

Understand that these fixes don't make the File in Use dialog go away, they just correct the problem of showing bogus user name information on the dialog itself.

Excel 2007 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2598133

Excel 2010 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2598143

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/61fdf388-e674-4a54-9c2e-0c1faf2cd4f7/word-and-excel-show-locked-for-editing-by-another-user-when-opened-from-file-explorer?forum=officeitproprevious